# Pasting artihmetic mean VBA

Tags: excel, vba, paste

Let's say I have two Excel Workbooks(in reality I have one sheet results and maybe a hundered other workbooks containing data). I would like to create a macro that allows me to take the arithmetic mean of a selection and paste that into my active cell. I have written a macro that allows me to paste copied values between different workbooks, really simple:

```
Sub PasteVal()
    Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

Trying to do the arithmetic mean copying does not work, however:

```
Sub PasteMean()
     ActiveCell.PasteSpecial (Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Selection))
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

did you try ?
`activecell.value=Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Selection)`

Comment: Yes, gets me a: "Runtime error '1004'" unable to get the Average property of the worksheetfunction class

Comment: what is the content of your selection ? you need at least one value. try to remove the worksheetfunction. keyword to get the true err msg.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16606827)

Comment: @Iehrlich, This is well an answer and should work. I request clarification to understand why it doesn't work in this specific case (i suspect no or invalid data) via comment.

Answer (score 0):

casually stumbled upon this post. consider the xlPasteSpecial method with
XlPasteSpecialOperation Enumeration.

xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd
xlPasteSpecialOperationDivide
xlPasteSpecialOperationMultiply
xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
xlPasteSpecialOperationSubtract

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1") 
.Range("C1:C5").Copy 
.Range("D1:D5").PasteSpecial _ 
Operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd 
End With
```